# Scala: working with video

Tags: scala, video, video-processing

I've been hard pressed to find anything in search engines. It seems that adding "video" to the search query makes the search engines think that I want to watch a video [tutorial].

How do I read, play, and potentially (though this is not presently necessary) edit video files with Scala?
What libraries are available? What general useful information can you give?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much aware of any video processing libraries specifically for Scala, but you can use pretty much anything that works for Java. Out of my head, I would suggest taking a look at Processing and [its video library](https://github.com/processing/processing-video). You might then go directly to the source libraries they use, e.g. gstreamer-java.